# Pyspark get predecessor value

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I have a dataset similar to this one

| exp | pid | mat | pskey | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CR | P | 1-CR-P | 1 |
| 1 | M | C | 1-M-C | 2 |
| 1 | CR | C | 1-CR-C | 3 |
| 1 | PP | C | 1-PP-C | 4 |
| 2 | CR | P | 2-CR-P | 1 |
| 2 | CR | P | 2-CR-P | 1 |
| 2 | M | C | 2-M-C | 2 |
| 2 | CR | C | 2-CR-C | 3 |
| 2 | CR | C | 2-CR-C | 3 |
| 2 | CR | C | 2-CR-C | 3 |
| 2 | CR | C | 2-CR-C | 3 |
| 2 | CR | C | 2-CR-C | 3 |
| 2 | PP | C | 2-PP-C | 4 |
| 2 | PP | C | 2-PP-C | 4 |
| 2 | PP | C | 2-PP-C | 4 |
| 2 | PP | C | 2-PP-C | 4 |
| 2 | PP | C | 2-PP-C | 4 |
| 3 | M | C | 3-M-C | 2 |
| 4 | CR | P | 4-CR-P | 1 |
| 4 | M | C | 4-M-C | 2 |
| 4 | CR | C | 4-CR-C | 3 |
| 4 | PP | C | 4-PP-C | 4 |

What I need is to get pskey of the predecessor for the same exp giving the following relation:

order 1 -> no predecessor

order 2 -> no predecessor

order 3 -> [1,2]

order 4 -> [3]

And add those values to a new column called `predecessor`

The expected result would be like:

```
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|exp|pid|mat|pskey |order|predecessor                             |
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------------------------------+
|1  |CR |P  |1-CR-P|1    |null                                    |
|1  |M  |C  |1-M-C |2    |null                                    |
|1  |CR |C  |1-CR-C|3    |[1-CR-P, 1-M-C ]                        |
|1  |PP |C  |1-PP-C|4    |[1-CR-C]                                |
|3  |M  |C  |3-M-C |2    |null                                    |
|2  |CR |P  |2-CR-P|1    |null                                    |
|2  |CR |P  |2-CR-P|1    |null                                    |
|2  |M  |C  |2-M-C |2    |null                                    |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C]                         |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C]                         |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C]                         |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C]                         |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C]                         |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]                                |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]                                |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]                                |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]                                |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]                                |
|4  |CR |P  |4-CR-P|1    |null                                    |
|4  |M  |C  |4-M-C |2    |null                                    |
|4  |CR |C  |4-CR-C|3    |[4-CR-P, 4-M-C]                         |
|4  |PP |C  |4-PP-C|4    |[4-CR-C]                                |
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------------------------------+
```

I am quite new to pyspark so I have no clue how to manage it.

Comment: you only have 4 "order" values ? Can you add (edit your question) the expected output based on your sample input? It is difficult to understand the exact output for exp = 2 and order = 3

Comment: I added the expected results. Don't know why is giving me problems with the format. I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differents cases on `order` are handled with `when`. You aggregate the values with a `collect_set` to get unic identifiers:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window 

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "predecessor",
    F.when(
        F.col("order") == 3,
        F.collect_set(F.col("pskey")).over(
            Window.partitionBy("exp").orderBy("order").rangeBetween(-2, -1)
        ),
    ).when(
        F.col("order") == 4,
        F.collect_set(F.col("pskey")).over(
            Window.partitionBy("exp").orderBy("order").rangeBetween(-1, -1)
        ),
    ),
)
```

the result :

```py
df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------+                                     
|exp|pid|mat|pskey |order|predecessor     |
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------+
|1  |CR |P  |1-CR-P|1    |null            |
|1  |M  |C  |1-M-C |2    |null            |
|1  |CR |C  |1-CR-C|3    |[1-CR-P, 1-M-C ]|
|1  |PP |C  |1-PP-C|4    |[1-CR-C]        |
|3  |M  |C  |3-M-C |2    |null            |
|2  |CR |P  |2-CR-P|1    |null            |
|2  |CR |P  |2-CR-P|1    |null            |
|2  |M  |C  |2-M-C |2    |null            |
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C ]|
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C ]|
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C ]|
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C ]|
|2  |CR |C  |2-CR-C|3    |[2-CR-P, 2-M-C ]|
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]        |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]        |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]        |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]        |
|2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4    |[2-CR-C]        |
|4  |CR |P  |4-CR-P|1    |null            |
|4  |M  |C  |4-M-C |2    |null            |
+---+---+---+------+-----+----------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Is almost that, but for example for |2  |PP |C  |2-PP-C|4  the result would be only the value from order 3 -> [2-CR-C]

Comment: in your question, you write `order 4 -> [4]`. If you want to do `order 4 -> [3]`, then change `rangeBetween(0,0)` with `rangeBetween(-1,-1)`

Comment: my mistake! sorry!

Comment: @Daniel I updated the code and result with `rangeBetween(-1,-1)` and added a distinct for the list creation.

Comment: Thanks Steven! the rangeBetween and the collect_set was exactly what I needed!